# jquery load more content onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, load

This is what I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
  $("#feed-page").load("feed.php #first-feed");

  $('.feed-load').click(function(){   
    $("#feed-page").load("feed.php #second-feed" ,  hideLoading);
    $(".feed-load .button-content").css( "display" , "none" );
    $('.feed-load-img').css( "display" , "block" );
  });

  function hideLoading() {  
    $(".feed-load .button-content").css( "display" , "block" );
    $(".feed-load .feed-load-img").css( "display" , "none" ); 
  }
}); // end document ready
```

My problem is that when I click on "load more" what happens is that the content gets swapped out.

That is not what I want to happen, I just want the content to all stay meaning the content that is already there on page load I want that to stay however when I click on "load more" I would like that content to stay but for some reason the content that was originally there gets swapped out with the new content which I don't want to happen.

A live example can be found here: http://www.cyberfanatic.com

Comment: My man... have you done any work yourself?

Comment: Please post your code on http://jsfiddle.net then come back here and post the link to your jsfiddle.

Comment: I would answer this but http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: okay i have added what i have tried so far to the question so please review the question sorry for the way i posted it.

Answer (score 3):

The issue with your current code is that after the user clicks the button, you are loading the new data over the existent one. See [jQuery .load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

What you need is to [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) the new data, in order to preserve the existent one:

```
// on click
$('.feed-load').click(function(){   

  // load the new data to an element
  $("<div>").load("feed.php #second-feed", function() {

    // all done, append the data to the '#feed-page'
    $("#feed-page").append($(this).find("#second-feed").html());

    // call your function
    hideLoading();
  });

  // continue the remaining of your code...
  $(".feed-load .button-content").css( "display" , "none" );
  $('.feed-load-img').css( "display" , "block" );
});
```

---

### EDITED

Append with some animation as requested at the comment:

```
...
// all done, append the data to the '#feed-page'
var $html   = $(this).find("#second-feed").html(),
    $newEle = $('<div id="second-feed" />').attr("style", 'display:none;').html($html);

$("#feed-page").append($newEle);
$('#second-feed').slideToggle();
...
```

See this [Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/V4QDF/)!

Comment: thank you so much however i was wondering if you can add a peice of code to animate say slideDown because i don't like the way it just appears i haven't tried anyting because i don't know where to begin

Comment: @user1405690, just added one Fiddle example and the relevant code to have an animation for the appended content.