# load more content onclick using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a service which gives 20 records per each page, now i want to modify this pagination process to load more content process which means when page is loading it shows first 20 records after click on load more content button it gives first 20 records plus next 20 records(total 40 records). I completely don't know how to do this process.. Can any one suggest me.

Comment: May be right now you ar using .html(). To achieve what you want use .append() to append data with current records.

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11022888/jquery-load-more-content-onclick

Answer (score 0):

[click this jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/sEwM6/1054/)

**html**

```
<table id="personDataTable">
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
    </tr>

</table>
<div id="More">load more</div>
```

**js**

```
var Default=4;
var DefaultViewMore=5;
var inc=0;
var data=[
            {
            id: 1,
            firstName: "Peter",
            lastName: "Jhons"},
        {
            id: 2,
            firstName: "David",
            lastName: "Bowie"},
             {
            id: 3,
            firstName: "Peter",
            lastName: "Jhons"},
        {
            id: 4,
            firstName: "David",
            lastName: "Bowie"},
    {
            id: 5,
            firstName: "Peter",
            lastName: "Jhons"},
        {
            id: 6,
            firstName: "David",
            lastName: "Bowie"},
             {
            id: 7,
            firstName: "Peter",
            lastName: "Jhons"},
        {
            id: 8,
            firstName: "David",
            lastName: "Bowie"},
    {
            id: 9,
            firstName: "Peter",
            lastName: "Jhons"},
        {
            id: 10,
            firstName: "David",
            lastName: "Bowie"},
             {
            id: 11,
            firstName: "Peter",
            lastName: "Jhons"},
        {
            id: 12,
            firstName: "David",
            lastName: "Bowie"},

    {
            id: 13,
            firstName: "Peter",
            lastName: "Jhons"},
        {
            id: 14,
            firstName: "David",
            lastName: "Bowie"},
             {
            id: 15,
            firstName: "Peter",
            lastName: "Jhons"},
        {
            id: 16,
            firstName: "David",
            lastName: "Bowie"},
        ]

drawTable(data,Default);


$("#More").click(function () {
   Default=Default+ DefaultViewMore;
    drawTable(data,Default);
});

function drawTable(data,bindRow) {

    for (var i = inc; i < data.length; i++) {

        drawRow(data[i]);

        if(data.length-1 == i)
            {
               $("#More").hide();
            }

        if(i==bindRow)
            {
                inc=bindRow;
                break;
            }
    }
}

function drawRow(rowData) {
    var row = $("<tr />")
    $("#personDataTable").append(row); //this will append tr element to table... keep its reference for a while since we will add cels into it
    row.append($("<td>" + rowData.id + "</td>"));
    row.append($("<td>" + rowData.firstName + "</td>"));
    row.append($("<td>" + rowData.lastName + "</td>"));
}
```

**CSS**

```
table {
  border: 1px solid #666;   
    width: 100%;
}
th {
  background: #f8f8f8; 
  font-weight: bold;    
    padding: 2px;
}
```